# return an array of objects filtering by another object id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help for a react project about a quiz app. I have a database (for now I'm using firebase realtime database) with a collection of questions and another collection of answers. The questions have an Id, a title, and a description; the answers have an Id, the description, and the question_id representing at what question they belong.

Questions:

[image: example of question's database]

Answers:

[image: example of answer's database]

Here is my code for the questionCard, where i fectched data from the database and collected questions and answers into 2 different arrays of objects:

```
const baseURL_Q =
  'https://test-manager-14360-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/domanda.json';
const baseURL_A =
  'https://test-manager-14360-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/risposta.json';

export default function QuestionCard() {
  const [onTime, setOnTime] = useState(true);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest: getQuestions } = useAxios();
  const { sendRequest: getAnswers } = useAxios();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setValue(true);
  };

  const handleSelectedItem = (index) => {
    setClickedIndex(index);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const goToNext = () => {
    setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    setValue(false);
    setClickedIndex(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
      const loadedQuestions = [];

      for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
        loadedQuestions.push({
          id: questionKey,
          id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
          tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
          testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
          immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
          eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
        });
      }
      setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
    };
    getQuestions(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL_Q,
      },
      transformQuestions
    );
  }, [getQuestions]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const transformAnswers = (answerObj) => {
      const loadedAnswers = [];

      for (const answerKey in answerObj) {
        loadedAnswers.push({
          id: answerKey,
          domanda_id: answerObj[answerKey].domanda_id,
          corretta: answerObj[answerKey].corretta,
          testo: answerObj[answerKey].testo,
          immagine: answerObj[answerKey].immagine,
        });
      }
      setAnswers(loadedAnswers);
    };
    getAnswers(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL_A,
      },
      transformAnswers
    );
  }, [getAnswers]);

  let questionsTitle = questions.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
  let questionId = questions.map((element) => `${element.id}`);
  let answerTitle = answers.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
  let answerQuestionId = answers.map((element) => `${element.domanda_id}`);


  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            minWidth: 275,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingLeft: '50%',
            paddingBottom: '5%',
            position: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Card
            variant='outlined'
            sx={{
              minWidth: 400,
            }}
          >
            {onTime ? (
              <>
                <CardContent>
                  <Grid container spacing={0}>
                    <Grid item xs={8}>
                      <Typography
                        variant='h5'
                        component='div'
                        fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                      >
                        Nome Test
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <CountDown setOnTime={setOnTime} seconds={1000} />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>

                  <LinearProgress variant='determinate' value={1} />

                  <Typography
                    sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5 }}
                    fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                    fontWeight={'bold'}
                  >
                    {questionsTitle[currentQuestionIndex]}
                  </Typography>

                  <ButtonGroup
                    fullWidth
                    orientation='vertical'
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={clickedIndex === 1}
                      onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(1)}
                    >
                      Risposta 1
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={clickedIndex === 2}
                      onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(2)}
                    >
                      Risposta 2
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={clickedIndex === 3}
                      onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(3)}
                    >
                      Risposta 3
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={clickedIndex === 4}
                      onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(4)}
                    >
                      Risposta 4
                    </ListItemButton>
                  </ButtonGroup>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                  <Button
                    onClick={goToNext}
                    disabled={!value}
                    variant='contained'
                    size='small'
                  >
                    Avanti
                  </Button>
                </CardActions>
              </>
            ) : (
              <div>TEMPO ESAURITO</div>
            )}
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

How can I get just the answers related to a specific question Id and render them into the ListItemButtons? I really don't know where to start

Comment: Please create a minimum reproducible example. Your problem seems nothing to have to do with react, it's just about data structures. Provide your input data, the expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why not just select all from both your question and answer table then sort them into a map object or even just an object? You can just filter through them by the question id's and then store them into a question state that you can display and update as the question changes.

Comment: I have 2 arrays of objects: `questions=[{id:1, text: question1}, {id:2, text:question2},...]`  and `answers:[{id:1, text: answer1, question_id:1}, {id:2, text:answer2, questions_id:2}...]`. When for example the Question card is showing the Question1, i want to rendere just the answers that have question_id:1, and so on for every question

Comment: @boredProjects Thank you! That's exactly what I'd like to do, the problem is that I'm new at coding and I really don't know how to do it. I was trying with `for(const id in questions){
    let answersToQuestion = answers.filter((element)=> element.domanda_id === questionKey)
    console.log(answersToQuestion)
  }` but of course it doesn't work. Can someone show me the right method, id it's not too much?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request just the answers for a specific question, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering).

Here that would look something like:

```
https://test-manager-14360-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/risposta.json?orderBy="domanda_id"&equalTo=2
```

So I added these parameters to the end of the URL:

```
orderBy="domanda_id"&equalTo=2
```

You will need to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to your database's rules, which would look something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "risposta": {
      ...
      ".indexOn": "domanda_id"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem here is that I can't modify the database because, so it has to work as it is now

Comment: You will need to add the index in order to be able to query the data through the REST API. There's no way to perform the query without that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯